# How to filter Q/A based on user (Questioner+Answerer)?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

I want to filter question according to combination of Questioner & Answerer.

1. Example if I want to search question(s) that asked by user:111 and answered by user:222 then how can I do that?

   Advanced search like `user:111 is:question user:222 is:answer` is **not suitable** for it.
2. Also I want to search Q/A both by one user (**shared knowledge**) then how can I search that?

   Advanced search like `user:me is:question is:answer` is **not suitable** for it.

---

Here `user:111` and `user:222` are used for only example in real they are not exist.
*If 1st case solved then 2nd is automatically solved.*